# Getting a "NoSuchMethodError" when trying to create an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I'm having trouble creating an array of arrays.  I have this

```
  data_cols = [[], []]
  lines.each do |line|
    parts = [0, *shared_space_indexes, line.size].each_cons(2).map { |a, b| line[a...b].strip }
    parts.each_with_index do |part, index|
      data_cols[index][data_cols[index] ? data_cols[index].size : 0] = part
    end
  end
```

But I get a "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" error on the "data_cols[index][data_cols[index] ? data_cols[index].size : 0] = part" line.  What I'm trying to do is for each parts array, push each item in "parts" onto its own array correspoding to the index of that element in parts.  So, for instance, if the first iteration of the loop has parts equal to

```
[1, 5, 8, 12]
```

I would have a data_cols array that looks like

```
[[1], [5], [8], [12]]
```

and if the next iteration of the loop had a parts array that looked like

```
[19, 20, 21, 22]
```

the data_cols array would then be changed to

```
[[1, 19], [5, 20], [8, 21], [12, 22]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test without knowing what `lines` and `shared_space_indexes` look like.

## 2 columns → a matrix

#### zip

For the second part of your question you can use :

```
[1, 5, 8, 12].zip([19, 20, 21, 22])
#=> [[1, 19], [5, 20], [8, 21], [12, 22]]
```

#### transpose

```
[[1, 5, 8, 12],[19, 20, 21, 22]].transpose
#=> [[1, 19], [5, 20], [8, 21], [12, 22]]
```

With [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), both arrays need to have the same size.

## 3 columns → matrix

```
array1 = [1, 5, 8, 12]
array2 = [19, 20, 21, 22]
array3 = [99, 88, 77, 66]

p [array1, array2, array3].transpose
#=> [[1, 19, 99], [5, 20, 88], [8, 21, 77], [12, 22, 66]]
```

## columns → rows

If you have an array of arrays :

```
arrays = [
  [1, 5, 8, 12],
  [19, 20, 21, 22],
  [99, 88, 77, 66]
] 

p arrays.transpose
#=> [[1, 19, 99], [5, 20, 88], [8, 21, 77], [12, 22, 66]]
```

So in your case, I'd just concentrate on creating an array of arrays with the same length, and use `transpose` at the end.

## matrix + column → matrix

As you noticed, if you have

```
data_cols = [[1, 19], [5, 20], [8, 21], [12, 22]]
arr       = [99, 88, 77, 66]
```

`data_cols.zip(arr)` would produce a weird half-nested array :

```
[[[1, 19], 99], [[5, 20], 88], [[8, 21], 77], [[12, 22], 66]]
```

You can use :

```
p data_cols.zip(arr).map(&:flatten)
#=> [[1, 19, 99], [5, 20, 88], [8, 21, 77], [12, 22, 66]]
```

Comment: THanks but there is one issue.  If data_cols is "[[1, 19], [5, 20], [8, 21], [12, 22]]", and I have an array taht is [99, 88, 77, 66], doing [data_cols, arr].transpose produces "[[[1, 19], 99], [[5, 20], 88], [[8, 21], 77], [[12, 22], 66]]", but I'd like it to produce "[[1, 19, 99], [5, 20, 88], [8, 21, 77], [12, 22, 66]]".  Does taht make sense?  I appreciate all your help with all my numerous questions.